# Captionof+label creates link anchored to the caption, not the proof

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, proof-package

I have a proof (bussproof) that is inside the `center` environment, and I put `captionof` inside it, with a `label` after it. When I click on an `autoref` of the label, it jumps to the caption but not to the top of the proof.

Here's the outline of my code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \AxiomC{$A$}
    \UnaryInfC{$B$}
    \DisplayProof
    \captionof{figure}{Proof sketch}
    \label{fig:proof-schema}
\end{center}

\autoref{fig:proof-schema}

\end{document}
```

I've tried putting the `captionof` and `label` outside the `center` environment, but that doesn't change anything. If I put the `captionof` in front of the proof, it would link to the caption but the caption would appear before the proof.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, as usual here, make your given code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Ok, I've edited the post, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behaviour is mentioned in `caption` package documentation. when you use the command `\captionof` the hyperlink anchor is located in the caption, despite `hypcap` is `true`. An alternative is to use `\captionsetup` and `\caption` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{center}
        \captionsetup{type=figure}
        \AxiomC{$A$}
        \UnaryInfC{$B$}
        \DisplayProof
        \caption{Proof sketch}
        \label{fig:proof-schema}
    \end{center}
    
    \autoref{fig:proof-schema}
    
\end{document}
```

The idea is to use `\captionsetup` to define the type of float environment you want. This creates a hyperlink anchor, so it is better used at the start of the environment (before your contents). Then you can typeset your caption with `\caption` instead of `\captionof`

Comment: thank you! this worked!